# MailMerge: No fixed width font?

Tags: visual-c++, cpu-word, mailmerge

I am trying to send data to a specific MergeField. The data are sent correctly. Each line of the data has for specific characters. For example the data to the field may be:

12345           FIRST\nABCDE.F         SECOND

(it cannot get the newline so i just so it through character \n)

Now in the printed document each character has its one width, '1' is smaller than 'E' for example. So the data are not alligned within the field. I tried the following fonts: Arial, Tahoma, Courier New. Nothing helped.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Ps the data are sent through an executable built by Visual C++ 5.0!!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a tab-stop based layout. Set your tab-stops every, say, centimetre or so (i.e. just big than the widest character in your font) and add a tab before each element that needs to be aligned.

With this you shouldn't need to find a fixed width font and can use something more attractive.

Edit: Out of interest, I wonder why you have no luck with Courier New which is fixed width.

Maybe you could post a screenshot somewhere so we can have a look at your problem in more detail.

Comment: The proble is that all the data that I am trying to align is in a single field. This is because the data are not the same all the time. It is hard to create a screenshot as this is in the printed doc. 'ABCDE.F     SECOND' this is a line and exceeds the previous one which is this one:  '12345      FIRST' all though the number of characters are the same (both have 5 spaces)! This is the problem i am facing :(

Comment: So does using Courier New not solve this problem? It's a fixed width font and so all characters should align correctly.

Comment: No, unfortunately does not solve the problem and it is weird. I also tried Shift+F9 to confirm that the font was there and still did not wrok!

Answer (score 0):

Try Courier - it does not have kerning (kerning = variable character width)

Also in the Font window there is a check box that allows you to apply kerning to fonts of a certain size or above - setting this value to a large font size *may* remove kerning.